# Can't access PFObject as dictionary

Tags: dictionary, parse-platform

I am starting to use Parse and in the documentation it has examples to use the PFObject as an NSDitionary like this:

```
// Create the post
PFObject *myPost = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Post"];
myPost[@"title"] = @"I'm Hungry";
```

but i am getting a compiler error: 
"Expected method to write dictionary element not found on object of type "PFObject"

But if I access the myPost PFObject like this, it works:

```
[myPost setObject:@"I'm Hungry" forKey:@"title"];
```

What is the problem?

I though that PFObject could be accesses as a dictionary?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would check that you are using the latest version of the Parse SDK. This is new functionality and my guess is you haven't downloaded the SDK since this feature was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

when i try your code at my side it gives me success message. I think you are using old parse library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading latest XCode should help. Subscript syntax is available from Xcode 4.4+